# Can one find the Euler characeristic of two dimensional manifold without integrating Gaussian curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

Is there any idea of evaluating integer topological invariant that is given by the integral form, say the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, by “not doing the integral”?

In other words, is there any way to evaluate the global quantity by only looking at local quantities?

---

I want to calculate the Chern number of physical system, especially the Chern insulator. Conventionally we calculate the Chern number by integrating the Berry curvature in the full Brillouin zone. But my question is that whether there is any method of calculating the Chern number without any integration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I want to calculate the Chern number of physical system, especially the Chern insulator. Conventionally we calculate the Chern number by integrating the Berry curvature in the full Brillouin zone. But my question is that whether there is any method of calculating the Chern number without any integration.

Comment: @QM24 The above comment is written automatically by a bot. You should add your precisions in an edit of your question instead of as a comment

Comment: You can certainly do it by decomposing the surface into a collection of, say, triangles or rectangles and computing the Euler characteristic by counting vertices, edges, and faces. 

Or you could try to find a function with nondegenerate critical points and use the Hopf index theorem. 

Is this the kind of thing you’re looking for?

Comment: @Deane thanks, actually what I want is that is something different. If we look into the Gauss curvature K of some point, then that information is clearly local information, whereas the total Euler characteristic is global one. Then what does the local information, say K(x0) at some point x0 plays? Can we find the Euler characteristic without integrating K?

Comment: If you prefer (assuming that the curvature function $K$ is "generic"): Compute the total number $t$ of local minima and maxima of the function $K(x)$. Then compute the total number $s$ of saddle points of $K(x)$.  Lastly, $\chi= t-s$. Here $K$ can be any "generic" smooth function, but you use $K(x)$ if this is the information that you have.

Comment: The answer is no. Knowing the Gauss curvature at one point tells you nothing about what the global topology of the surface is. For example, you can have a sphere where at one particular point, the Gauss curvature is zero or negative. Similarly, you can have a $2$-manifold with negative Euler characteristic, where the Gauss curvature is sometimes positive.

Comment: thanks all! I appreciate your answers :)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is there any reference about the relation? I am majoring in physics, so have no idea how the relation comes out.

Comment: You can start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory (the first formula in "Morse Inequalities" section).